# How to achieve `groupby` rolling mean in dask?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a dataframe, and I want to `groupby` some attributes and calculate the `rolling` mean of a numerical column in Dask. I know there is no implementation in Dask for `groupby rolling` but I read an SO question which shows it was possible.

[Dask rolling function by group syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42172130/dask-rolling-function-by-group-syntax)

When I am using the same syntax from the post, I get an error :

`UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '�'.`

I do not understand why I am getting an unpickling error.
`df.groupby(by=path)[metric].apply(lambda df_g: df_g[metric].rolling(5).mean(), meta=(metric, 'f8')).compute()`
where `path` is a list of attribute columns, and `metric` is the numeric column.

I also tried the following:

```
def moving_avg(partition):
    return partition.rolling(5).mean()

df.groupby(by=path)[metric].apply(moving_avg, meta='f8').compute()
```

I use the rolling average function in Pyspark where I define the partitions by groupby and then roll a window over it.

Sample data :

```
           CATEGORY_NAME               MKT   ...         Growth   Sales
Date                                         ...                       
2017-01-07            TP              SIMS   ...         0.0000   17280
2017-01-07            TP           TOPRITE   ...        -0.4566    1825
2017-01-07            TP       GIANT HYPER   ...         0.0874   18417
2017-01-07            TP       GIANT HYPER   ...        -0.1359   10914
2017-01-07            TP       GIANT HYPER   ...         0.2245    4422
2017-01-07            TP           TOPRITE   ...         0.1084    1444
2017-01-07            TP       GIANT HYPER   ...         0.0542   18412
2017-01-07            TP            FENCER   ...         0.2766   25184
2017-01-07            TP       GIANT HYPER   ...        -0.0572   19466
2017-01-07            TP           TOPRITE   ...         0.1795    1503
2017-01-07            TP       GIANT HYPER   ...         0.0770   13615
```

Say I want to groupby `["CATEGORY_NAME", "MKT"]` and take a rolling average of `Sales`.

Answer (score 0):

See [Dask rolling function by group syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42172130/dask-rolling-function-by-group-syntax) for the answer. The UnpicklingError is unrelated to the question.