# Use dask to calculate moving average

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I am trying to calculate the moving average of a very large data set. The number of rows is approx 30M. To illustrate using pandas as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cust_id':['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'sales': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]})
df['mov_avg'] = df.groupby("cust_id")["sales"].apply(lambda x: x.ewm(alpha=0.5, adjust=False).mean())
```

Here I am using pandas to calculate the moving average. Using above it takes around 20 minutes to calculate on the 30M dataset. Is there a way to leverage DASK here?

Comment: Have you tried loading the data into a Dask dataframe and running your computation?

Comment: You may look at Dask rolling function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42172130/dask-rolling-function-by-group-syntax

Answer (score 5):

You can use Dask.delayed for your calculation. In the example below, a standard python function which contains the pandas moving average command is turned into a dask function using a @delayed decorator.

```
import pandas as pd
from dask import delayed

@delayed
def mov_average(x):
    x['mov_avg'] = x.groupby("cust_id")["sales"].apply(
                            lambda x: x.ewm(alpha=0.5, adjust=False).mean())
    return x

df = pd.DataFrame({'cust_id':['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
                   'sales': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]})

df['mov_avg'] = df.groupby("cust_id")["sales"].apply(
                            lambda x: x.ewm(alpha=0.5, adjust=False).mean())

df_1 = mov_average(df).compute()
```

Output

```
df
Out[22]: 
  cust_id  sales  mov_avg
0       a    100    100.0
1       a    200    150.0
2       a    300    225.0
3       b    400    400.0
4       b    500    450.0

df_1
Out[23]: 
  cust_id  sales  mov_avg
0       a    100    100.0
1       a    200    150.0
2       a    300    225.0
3       b    400    400.0
4       b    500    450.0
```

Alternatively, you could try converting (or reading your file) into a dask data frame. The visualization of the scheduler tasks shows the parallelization of the calculations. So, if your data frame is large enough you might get a reduction in your computation time. You could also try optimizing the number of data frame partitions.

```
from dask import dataframe

ddf = dataframe.from_pandas(df, npartitions=3)
ddf['emv'] = ddf.groupby('cust_id')['sales'].apply(lambda x: x.ewm(alpha=0.5, adjust=False).mean()).compute().sort_index()
ddf.visualize()
```

[image]

```
ddf.compute()

        cust_id     sales   emv
    0   a   100     100.0
    1   a   200     150.0
    2   a   300     225.0
    3   b   400     400.0
    4   b   500     450.0
```

Comment: There is no performance gain using  mov_average(df).compute() or mov_average(dask_df).compute(scheduler = 'processes') . Any idea what can improve the performance ?

Comment: You need to run processes in parallel, the calculations for you customer 'a' and 'b' are independent